# Using wild cards in JMX key to get a list of queue attributes

Tags: jmx, zabbix, activemq-artemis

I'm using Zabbix to monitor ActiveMQ Artemis via JMX. I'd like to retrieve a JSON object with the message count for all the queues - if that's possible.

[Here](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery/jmx) is my main source of understanding on this subject:

I can get all the attributes for all the queues like this:

```
jmx.get[attributes,"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=*,component=addresses,address=*,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=*,queue=*"]
```

Here is an example of a few items from the array:

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "name of this queue",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "value": "MAO.SOF.User.Import.Queue",
    "object": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,address=\"MAO.SOF.User.Import.Topic\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"multicast\",queue=\"MAO.SOF.User.Import.Queue\""
},
{
    "name": "Address",
    "description": "address this queue is bound to",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "value": "MAO.SOF.User.Import.Topic",
    "object": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,address=\"MAO.SOF.User.Import.Topic\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"multicast\",queue=\"MAO.SOF.User.Import.Queue\""
},
{
    "name": "MessageCount",
    "description": "number of messages currently in this queue (includes scheduled, paged, and in-delivery messages)",
    "type": "java.lang.Long",
    "value": "0",
    "object": "org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=\"0.0.0.0\",component=addresses,address=\"MAO.SOF.User.Import.Topic\",subcomponent=queues,routing-type=\"multicast\",queue=\"MAO.SOF.User.Import.Queue\""
}
```

However, now I'm trying to figure out how to filter for only `MessageCount`. I've tried these two, but it returns an empty array:

```
jmx.get[attributes,"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=*,component=addresses,address=*,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=*,queue=*,name=MessageCount"]
```

```
jmx.get[attributes,"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=*,component=addresses,address=*,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=*,queue=*,attribute=MessageCount"]
```

[Edit]

Here is my current solution for this. Here is an example of the key I'm using:

```
jmx.get[attributes,"org.apache.activemq.artemis:broker=*,component=addresses,address=*,subcomponent=queues,routing-type=*,queue=*"]
```

This gets all of the JMX properties for all of the queues. Then under the Preprocessing tab I add a JSONPath query:

```
$.[?(@.name=='MessageCount')]
```

This filters for only the message count property. Then I use a little javascript to make a string.

```
var object = JSON.parse(value);
var returnString = ""; 
for (var i=0; i<object.length; i++) {
  if (object[i].value > 5) {
    returnString = returnString + object[i].object.substring(object[i].object.lastIndexOf("\",queue=\"")+9, object[i].object.length-1) + " has " + object[i].value + " messages pending.\n"; 
  }
}
if (returnString.length==0) {
  returnString = "clear"; 
}
return returnString;
```

This simply loops through the array and if it finds a massage count greater than the value (5 in this example) it append the queue name and count to a string. If no queues were found with >5, I set the string to "clear".

Then when I create an action, I trigger a message if the value isn't "clear".

Comment: Thanks Justin. I updated my question with a little more progress.

Comment: I updated my question with my current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Zabbix documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery/jmx#using_jmxget):

> When using `jmx.get[]` for discovery, low-level discovery macros can be defined separately in the custom [LLD macro](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery#discovery_rule) tab of the discovery rule configuration, using JSONPath to point to the required values.

[Documentation on JSONPath functionality](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/appendix/preprocessing/jsonpath_functionality) is available from Zabbix as well.

You can't just add `name=MessageCount` or `attribute=MessageCount` to the MBean name as those aren't actually a part of the MBean's name. "MessageCount" is an *attribute* retrieved from the MBean. Therefore you need to fetch it some other way (e.g. using JSONPath).